# How to provide dynamic input value / id for radio buttons being printed in for loop jsp

Tags: arrays, jsp

I am creating an input form in tabular form and unable to assign dynamic values to the radio buttons being printer in for loop. When I try to make a selection it only selects either of the options that are printed say 3 times.

Please help!

This is the snippet in use:

For loop is counting number of categories:

```
            for ( int i = 0 ; i< tempsysDetails1.getCategory().size() ; i++)
```

Then there is a table: that generates Green / Red values and name of categories as:

```
            <td align="left"> <%out.println( tempsysDetails1.getCategory().get(i)); %> </td>

<td align="left"> <input type="radio" value="green[i]" <label class="radio"><font color="green">Green</font></label>><input type="radio" value="red[i]" <label class="radio"><font color="red">Red</font></label>>
```

">

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. How are you running the `for` loop?

Comment: @VHS I updated the question. Please check. I am able to select both red and green button in the row now.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set value instead of name

So instead:

```
<input type="radio" name="foo[i]i"
```

Try:

```
 <input type="radio" value="foo[i]i"
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `JavaScript for loop`, use JSP `for` loop.

```
<c:forEach var="category" items="${categories}">
    <td align="left"> 
       <input type="radio" value="green${category.index}"> 
           <label class="radio">
              <font color="green">Green</font>
           </label>
       </input>
       <input type="radio" value="red${category.index}">
           <label class="radio">
               <font color="red">Red</font>
           </label>
       </input>
</c:forEach>
```